# Limiting date range in HTML 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a input field with type date

```
<input type="date" id="datepick" name="mybirthday" placeholder="Birthdate(MM/DD/YYYY)" />
```

Here I want to limit the date range that the user can choose. To be more specific, I dont want the user to choose a birthdate like 22/08/2015. How can I do this?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html

Comment: Sidenote: you shouldn't generally include the date format in the placeholder as the format for an HTML5 date will be determined by the user's local settings.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Use the `min` and `max` attributes:

```html
<label>Enter a date before 1989-10-30:</label>
<input type="date" name="myDate" max="1989-10-29">

<label>Enter a date after 2001-01-01:</label>
<input type="date" name="myDate" min="2001-01-02">
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about that but I remember reading somewhere that HTML5 datepickers are based on browser locale and might not give you desired output in all your visitors' browsers. E.g. in the US the date format is MM/dd/yyyy whereas in the UK it is dd/MM/yyyy.

I didn't want to deal with all that or leave it to luck so I ended up using jQueryUI datepicker.. Many events are already readily available for you there...