# Restricting date input to five days from current

Tags: jquery, html, datetime

I'm currently trying to create a date input box to disable a user from selecting any date that is not more than 5 days from the current date.

Is it possible to accomplish this using just something like this:

```
<label for="startDate">Start Date:</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="startDate"       placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" />
```

Or is there an easier way - or a different way to approach this problem?

Comment: read especially this part http://stackoverflow.com/a/17292150/3279496

Comment: are you using bootstrap?

Comment: @kamal0808 Yeah I'm using bootstrap - is there anything worth looking at there?

Comment: yes, go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11933173/how-to-restrict-the-selectable-date-ranges-in-bootstrap-datepicker and check out the accepted answer

Comment: @kamal0808 I only see mentions of start and end dates there, but I'm looking for something that would only allow something to be scheduled from todaysDate+5.