# validation in date picker, only show last 5 month date from current date

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to validate the date in date picker from today to last till 5 month.
EG. if today date is 25/08/2017. calendar last month date valid 24/03/2017. Means user cant fill date before 24/03/2017. Disable the date before 5 month.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have some example code?

Comment: Seems like duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17292087/limiting-date-range-in-html-5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limiting date range in HTML 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17292087/limiting-date-range-in-html-5)

Answer (score 0):

You can use minDate function. Check this -

```
var date = new Date();
var currentMonth = date.getMonth();
var currentDate = date.getDate();
var currentYear = date.getFullYear();

$('#calendar123').datepicker({
    minDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth-3, currentDate),
    maxDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth+3, currentDate)
});
```

Comment: This is not working. If this is right, please give the link of jsfiddle or any other editor

Comment: Datepicker is not loading. Fix that first. You can do that. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this also..

$('#calendar123').datepicker({
    minDate: "-05m"
});

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you.

```js
$("input.DateFrom").datepicker({
    minDate:'-5m',
    maxDate:'0'
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="demo">

<p>Date: <input type="text" class="DateFrom" id="datepicker"></p>

</div><!-- End demo -->
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to explain why your suggestion will work.

Comment: you may refer to the fiddle here is a working example as per your expectation http://jsfiddle.net/sain_anky/kGjdL/2147/

Comment: I have created a snippet in the answer based on your fiddle. You could do this using the `<>` button in the editor.