# remove days from input type data

Tags: php, html, css

how can I remove days from input type date? I added default data:

```
<input required class="data_inizio" type="date" name="inizio" value="2018-01-31">
```

But I would to remove previous days before that..

Comment: You mean, so that the user cannot choose earlier dates?

Comment: exactly user can choose only days after

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17292087/limiting-date-range-in-html-5

You can use min and max for that.

Comment: Doesn't work in all browsers though.

Comment: Can I do this in php?

Comment: You could use PHP for setting the min date, see my answer for an example.

Comment: but u have to select current day.. how can u do this in html?

Comment: If you don't use PHP, you could achieve the same thing using javaScript however. See my updated answer for a javaScript example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the min attribute, to only allow future dates. Like so: `<input required class="data_inizio" type="date" min="2018-01-31" name="inizio" value="2018-01-31">`. You will only need to replace the min value with a dynamic value which represents the current date. You could use something like php for that: .

So it would become:

```
<input required id="date-input" class="data_inizio" type="date" min="<?=date('Y-m-d', time())?>" name="inizio" value="2018-01-31">`.
```

You can find the browser support over here: [Browser_compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#Browser_compatibility)

Or setting the date using javaScript:

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if(dd<10) {
    dd = '0'+dd
} 

if(mm<10) {
    mm = '0'+mm
} 

today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;

document.getElementById("date-input").setAttribute('min', today);
```

Comment: doesn't work.. I've never use this syntax, I can't find the error D: For example.. min="<?" why not min ="<?php"

Comment: To use the php example, you will need to have php_short_tags enabled on your server. Or you just change the `<?=` to `<?php echo`. The `<?=` is just a shorter way of writing `<?php echo`. It does nothing extra, just saves you some typing.